# Can I simplify reading a short from binary data

Tags: java, io, nio, bytebuffer

I'm trying to simplify some code for decoding data in a file and I've written a test case to show the issue.

Given two bytes as `0xFe` and `0xFF`  I want that to be read as `0xFFFE` (65534), 
the existing code does

```
headerBuffer.get() & 0xff + (headerBuffer.get() & 0xff) * 256
```

I thought, if I made buffer byte order little endian, I could get same result by reading as a short. But I do not get same result, why not ?

`headerBuffer.getShort();`

```
public void testReadingOfShort() {
    ByteBuffer headerBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
    headerBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    headerBuffer.put((byte) 0xFE);
    headerBuffer.put((byte)0xFF);
    headerBuffer.position(0);
    int format = headerBuffer.get() & 0xff + (headerBuffer.get() & 0xff) * 256;
    headerBuffer.position(0);
    int formatNew = headerBuffer.getShort();
    System.out.println("Format:"+format+"("+ Hex.asHex(format)+")"+":FormatNew:"
            +formatNew+"("+Hex.asHex(formatNew)+")");
}
```

**Outputs**

> `Format:65534(0xfffe):FormatNew:-2(0xfffffffffffffffe)`

Comment: It's because a `short` is signed! Anyway, I suspect that the bug here is in that `Hex` class; show the code of all `.asHex()` methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do get the same value. The problem happens when you assign the `short` to an `int` on this line:

```
int formatNew = headerBuffer.getShort();
```

When you do this, Java performs *sign extension* to ensure that the numeric value in the `short` gets converted to the same numeric value in the `int`. In your case, that is -2.

The representation of -2 as a `short` is `0xFFFE`, while the `int` representation is `0xFFFFFFFE`. In other words, the sign bit of the `short` is copied into the additional upper bits of `int`.

You can address this by not assigning the `short` to `int`. You also need to make sure that your `Hex.asHex` has a proper overload for `short`, otherwise the same conversion would happen when `formatNew` gets passed as an argument.

Alternatively, if you would like to treat the value of the `short` as unsigned, and assign it to an `int`, you can mask the result with `0xFFFF`, like this:

```
int formatNew = headerBuffer.getShort() & 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: Okay Im understanding it better now in Java short is signed so the max value it will display is 32,767 so the value of 0xffFe (65534) is to large to be displayed as I require in a Short but I cant use ByteBuffers getInteger() because I only want to read two bytes not four. So i can either not assign it to integer, the issue being if comparing to other values such as an enum all literals have to be cast to short as assumes int by default, or do & 0xff to assign to int, not sure whihc is best really

Comment: @PaulTaylor I edited to add a way of treating your `short` as unsigned when reading it into an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

My hypothesis here is that in your `Hex` class you have a `.asHex()` method taking a `short` as an argument which does something like:

```
int value = (int) argument;
```

Tough luck. If you "upcast" from one integer type to another, the sign bit, if present, *is* carried. Which means that if you try and cast short 0xfffe to an int, you will NOT end up with 0x0000fffe but... 0xfffffffe. Hence your result.

If you wanted to cast it as an unsigned value you'd have to mask it, like so:

```
int value = (int) argument & 0xffff;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply obtain the desired value as

```
int formatNew = headerBuffer.getShort() & 0xFFFF;
```

or, alternatively, if you use Java 8:

```
int formatNew = Short.toUnsignedInt(headerBuffer.getShort());
```

This will basically drop all bits from the `int` that are not part of a `short`. But it won't relieve your from the responsibility of carefully checking where you expect unsigned values, and how to handle the (naturally) signed values in the respective context.